# Python Selenium print elements not element

Tags: python, selenium

In python Selenium I am attempting to print a list of class_name(meta). When I use browser.find.element only one value is returned. I then amend the script:-

```
demo = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("meta")
print demo.text
```

I get the following error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in 
    print demo.text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

I new to python & selenium but I have searched for a solution with no luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you are not iterating. You forget

```
for lang in demo:
```

Example code :-

```
langs = fire.find_elements_by_css_selector("#gt-sl-gms-menu div.goog-menuitem-content")
for lang in langs:
    print lang.text
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank You. Could not see the woods for the trees. Works Perfectly.